# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^2}$ convergent whenever $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n =\infty$ for unbounded $a_n >0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n>0$ be an unbounded sequence. Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n =\infty$.
I want to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^2}$$ is convergent.

What I have tried:

We know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/a_n$, so I have tried small $a_n$ such as $a_n=\ln n$ to check if it is divergent, but have failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. let $(s_n)$ be the partial sum sequence and note that $\frac {s_n-s_{n-1}} {s_n^{2}} \leq \frac  1 {s_n} -\frac 1 {s_{n-1}}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the quick answer. So it is convergent.

Comment: Yes it is convergent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't mean to bother you, but I think your inequality is flipped.

Comment: Yes, I should have written $\frac 1 {s_{n-1}}-\frac   1{s_n}$.